# Opening file geodatabase with raster datasets in QGIS 3

Tags: raster, qgis-3, file-geodatabase, import, arcgis-9.2

I wish to open a file geodatabase created using ArcGIS version 9 with QGIS 3. I am able to load the file using QGIS but only polygons are appearing but not the raster datasets. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Shapefile is a different format than file geodatabase. It is not possible to have a shapefile within a geodatabase. The vector tables in geodatabases are called feature classes.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to open rasters in a file geodatabase using QGIS. You will have to export them to another format which QGIS can read

Comment: yes sorry about that i meant feature classes. I am not  used to the terminologies used. basically when i load the geodatabase file in qgis all that shows up are polygons but not the tiff of the maps